# Using python for web databasing?

Tags: python

Is there a way to run a python script when loading an HTML page, to place variables on a page and set python variables based on `<input>`s? I already know python, and don't want to learn another language just for this.

Comment: Yes, Python is a pretty capable web development language. See [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) for example.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you mean by "web databasing"? What does "s" stand for?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/howto/webservers.html

Comment: "and don't want to learn another language just for this." hint for the future: if you want anyone here to help you then better don't say stuff like this.

Comment: @edem I typed "(less than)input(greater than)s", but it was removed

Comment: You didn't say if you mean client or server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a web framework such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) for this purpose. It allows you to construct a web page using Python. It also allows you to use a database from which you can retrieve and store data.

Both Flask and Django use a template engine that you can use to create HTML templates. You can pass variables to these templates and you can then place the values where you want.